# Installing a webscraper with maven

Tags: java, maven, terminal, warnings, archetypes

Trying to install a webscraper through maven through this [guide](https://ksah.in/introduction-to-web-scraping-with-java/). But I keep getting an error that the archetype doesn't exist, as show below:

I've tried going through the maven quick start [page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) and changing the maven goal several different ways which still results in the same error.

```
Ginos-MBP:apache-maven-3.6.2 ginocasolaro$ mvn archetype:generate -
DarchetypeGroupId=com.codetriage.scraper -DartifactId=codetriagescraper 
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart  -
DinteractiveMode=false

[WARNING] Specified archetype not found.
Downloading from central:  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/codetriage/scraper/maven-
archetype-quickstart/1.0/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0.pom
[WARNING] The POM for com.codetriage.scraper:maven-archetype-
quickstart:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading from central: 
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/codetriage/scraper/maven-
archetype-quickstart/1.0/maven-archetype-quickstart-1.0.jar

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
archetype-plugin:3.1.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-
pom: The desired archetype does not exist 
(com.codetriage.scraper:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.0) -> [Help 1]
```